# Keyboard offset no longer functions in SwiftUI 2

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, keyboard, offset

So I have an ObservableObject that sets a published variable 'currentHeight' to the height of the keyboard:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {

@Published var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

var _center: NotificationCenter

init(center: NotificationCenter = .default) {
    _center = center
    _center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    _center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        withAnimation {
           currentHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
    print("the KEYBOARD HEIGHT IS \(self.currentHeight)")
}

@objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
    withAnimation {
       currentHeight = 0
    }
    print("the KEYBOARD HEIGHT IS \(self.currentHeight)")
}
}
```

In my other views, I create an ObservedObject keyboardResponder and then inside the body of the view, I'll have for example some view where I set the vertical offset:

```
struct ViewName: View {
    @ObservedObject var keyboardResponder = KeyboardResponder()
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in 
            VStack {
                Text("this should be offset")
                .offset(y: -keyboardResponder.currentHeight)
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}
```

Before Xcode 12/SwiftUI 2 dropped, this worked like a charm but I think they changed something with how views refresh--anyone know what they changed and if there is a solution to my issue here?

EDIT: In my view, if I remove that edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all), it sort of works, but weirdly. Essentially, the view can only move up to the point where all views are just in frame, it doesn't allow the entire view to shift up (and out of screen view)...I'll throw in a vid to show what I mean...

This is the link for when there are some more elements that take up most of the screen (so the offset is extremely small)

https://youtu.be/jpID11-rZDs

This is the link for when there are fewer elements, so the offset gets that much larger

https://youtu.be/MjqX1qDEA6E

If the GeometryReader is enclosing the view, that's what REALLY breaks it and stops it from responding at all. If I remove it, then it functions as needed...

Comment: Do the print statements in the notification handler get called? If so add a print statement for `keyboardSize` also and see if it changes from zero.

Comment: @CenkBilgen the print statements do get called and it prints out the right value for currentHeight so keyboardSize must be changing...

Comment: But to be sure the change is happening at the time of the call, print out both - the local value from the notification `keyboardHeight` and the state `currentHeight`  inside the `if let` unwrapping block. Because one potential problem might be the NSValue cast. Also what happens if you remove the animation and set it directly?

Comment: @CenkBilgen I printed in both places (right after the setting of currentHeight and outside of that block) and it sets the value correctly. If I remove the animation, it changes nothing

Comment: It's always going to print something for currentHeight. Either the value extracted from the notification, ie keyboardHeight or the current value. So it's more important to print keyboardHeight or both.

Comment: My final suggestion is when you set currentHeight do so on explicitly on the main thread (it should already be, but make it explicit), ie DispatchQueue.main.async { self.currentHeight = ... } (or use the more current, closure based, notification observer function where you can specify the thread to handle on)

Comment: Seems working ?? (Xcode 12.0.1) I put a textfield above the text and it just moves up when the keyboard appears! @nickcoding

Comment: @EnesKaraosman The issue is also caused by enclosing the thing that has the offset with a GeometryReader {}

Comment: @CenkBilgen The issue is also caused by enclosing the thing that has the offset with a GeometryReader {}

Comment: @Asperi Any ideas? Usually you're a genius when it comes to swiftUI stuff

Answer (score 3):

As of the latest Swift, Xcode 12 and iOS14, I noticed that it is standard build in, when the textfield is not visible when typing. The screen is being risen with the keyboard height and shows the original field. Try this out with a scrollable view and 20 textfields for example.
Maybe you can get rid of your `observableheight` and do it without hard coding it.

[image]

Comment: I edited the original post, it having .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all) is for some reason causing the offset to not work and I'm not sure why.

Comment: The issue is also caused by enclosing the thing that has the offset with a GeometryReader {}